# Could not create stateless EJB

Tags: eclipse, jpa, glassfish, ejb, managed-bean

I have created a dynamic web project that includes EJB and JPA project.There is no problem in publishing the projects but when I call an EJB I am getting "Could not create stateless EJB" error.Here is my dao and ejb;

KitaplarDAO.java

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class KitaplarDAO extends GenericDAO<Kitaplar> implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public KitaplarDAO(Class<Kitaplar> entityClass) {
    super(entityClass);
}

@Override
public List<Kitaplar> findAll(String query) {
    return super.findAll("tumkitaplarigetir");
}
```

}

KitaplarFacadeImpl.java

```
@Stateless
public class KitaplarFacadeImpl implements KitaplarFacade,Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EJB
KitaplarDAO kitapDao;

@Override
public void save(Kitaplar kitaplar) {
    kitapDao.save(kitaplar);

}

@Override
public void update(Kitaplar kitaplar) {
    kitapDao.update(kitaplar);

}

@Override
public List<Kitaplar> findAll(String sorgu) {
    return kitapDao.findAll(sorgu);
}
```

KitaplarFacade.java

```
@Local
public interface KitaplarFacade {

public abstract void save(Kitaplar kitaplar);

public abstract void update(Kitaplar kitaplar);

public abstract void delete(Kitaplar kitaplar);

public abstract List<Kitaplar> findAll(String sorgu);
```

}

Here is my ManagedBean that used Facade service;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "kitaplariGetir")
@ViewScoped
public class KitaplariGetir implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Kitaplar> kitaplar = new ArrayList<Kitaplar>();

@EJB
KitaplarFacade service;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    initList();
}

private void initList() {
    try {
        kitaplar = service.findAll("tumkitaplarigetir");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<Kitaplar> getKitaplar() {
    return kitaplar;
}

public void setKitaplar(List<Kitaplar> kitaplar) {
    this.kitaplar = kitaplar;
}
```

}

Here is the stacktrace;

```
  Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
```

SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
SEVERE:     ... 102 more
SEVERE: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mesutemre.businesDAOs.KitaplarDAO
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer._constructEJBInstance(BaseContainer.java:1663)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1646)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)

Is there any problem with my codes? So how con I solve this problem.

Comment: The code looks correct. Please add the exception stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I have add the stacktrace

Comment: The important part of the exception is missing. Seems like something is wrong with your GenericDAO.

Comment: Exactly! The problem was in my GenericDAO. Thanks so much...

Comment: @emreturka, what was the problem in GenericDAO?